# CentOS, sendmail no corresponding with PHP

Tags: php, centos, sendmail

I have got trouble with sendmail functionnality on my CentOS (v6.) server.
No issue with mail sent through command lines but it stays impossible through PHP webpages.

Does someone have any idea about my problem? I have configured SendMail functionnality, do I have to configure anything else? (PHP service?)

Comment: try to use [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Comment: Have you checked the permissions - as far as I know the user who executes the php script (e.g. www-data) must be in the mail group to be capable of sending mails.

Comment: For each action, root user is used, so I have not configured anything else (no more permissions). Do I have to specific any further parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

(Started as a comment but it's getting a bit long)

You've provided no details of any attempt to resolve this yourself. What have you tried?

It would be helpful if you provided the output of:

```
<?php

$mc=ini_get('sendmail_path');
print "config: $mc <br />\n";
$p=explode(' ', $mc);
if ($p[0]) {
   passthru("ls -l " . $p[0]);
} else {
   print "no mua\n";
}
print "<br />\n";
print "running as " . posix_getlogin() . "\n<br />";
```

Comment: hi ! thx for your answer ! i have this with your script :

config: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Aug 6 11:06 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/mta

Comment: Ah yes, I'd forgotten about the Byzantine arrangement of sendmail in Redhat ( http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/kiss.html ) but it does show that your PHP is not running in a chroot jail. When you sent email from the command line did you do it using `sudo $yourwebserveruid sendmail -t -i <youremail` or something else?

Comment: I use the command : "mail toto@email.com" and it's good but i'am in root

Comment: Not good - you've only tested a tiny proportion of what's happenning here. Try replcing your sendmail_path with something to capture the text of an email then try again from the command line using '`sudo` as your wqebserver uid and `sendmail -t -i <yourCapturedEmailMsg` to test it properly.